# Sequelize: How to Include feilds in to an include model from its include model. (I don't know if it is even possible)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nodejs-server

I found a solution to this, but I am waiting for alternatives.
I am going to hold on to my answer, and see if there are alternatives to my solution. Any one looking for solution please leave comment and I'll post my answer.

I have following Models

```
User
|userid|fullname   |
|1     |Joe Klan   |
|2     |Tim Thomson|
|3     |Qasim Ali  |

Task
|taskid|taskname|
|1     |TSP     |
|2     |GS1     |
|3     |GS2     |
|4     |GS3     |

Record
|recordid|userid|taskid|units|boxes|orderdate |
|1       |1     |2     |23   |43   |2023-03-04|
|2       |1     |1     |18   |25   |2023-03-04|
|3       |1     |3     |12   |15   |2023-03-04|
|4       |1     |2     |26   |58   |2023-03-04|
|5       |1     |1     |23   |76   |2023-03-04|
|6       |2     |4     |34   |19   |2023-03-04|
|7       |2     |2     |51   |88   |2023-03-04|
|8       |2     |3     |15   |73   |2023-03-04|
```

```
User.hasMany(Record,{foreignKey: 'userid'});
Record.belongsTo(Task, { foreignKey: "taskid" });
```

What works

```
    const result = await User.findAll({
      where: { userid: id },
      attributes: ["userid", "fullname"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Record,
          attributes: ["recordid", "taskid", "units", "boxes"],
          include: [{ model: Task, attributes: ["taskname"] }],
        },
      ],
    });
```

Sample Results:

```
[
  {
    userid: 1,
    fullname: "Joe Klan",
    Records: [
      {
        recordid: 1,
        taskid: 3,
        units: 23,
        boxes: 43,
        Task: {
          taskname: "GS2",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

What I want to do:

```
const result = await User.findAll({
      where: { userid: id },
      attributes: ["userid", "fullname"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Record,
          attributes: ["recordid", "taskid","Task.taskname", "units",  "boxes"],
          include: [{ model: Task, attributes: [] }],
        },
      ],
    });
```

Required results:

```
[
  {
    userid: 1,
    fullname: "Joe Klan",
    Records: [
      {
        recordid: 1,
        taskid: 3,
        taskname: "GS2",
        units: 23,
        boxes: 43,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

When I try to this it says Unknown column 'Records.Task.taskname' in 'field list' which is actually correct that there is not such thing Records.Task.taskname but how can I make it to fetch Task.taskname to be included in Record attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Sequelize.col()` with `separate: true`. it can be used like:

```
const result = await User.findAll({
  attributes: ["userid", "fullname"],
  include: [
    {
      model: Record,
      attributes: ["recordid", "taskid", [Sequelize.col("Task.taskname"), "taskname"], "units", "boxes"],
      separate: true,
      include: [{ model: Task, attributes: [] }],
    },
  ],
 where: { userid: id }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I'll check this approach without separate sequelize.literal("`Records->Task`.`taskname`") also worked well. Thanks @Imran Azim

Comment: However this solution does not work if one requires to have grouping at primary level. using sequelize.literal("Records->Task.taskname") will be the only solution.